# Bootstrap modal body height not changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I am trying to increase the height of a single modal.

I have added height attributes to the div like so:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="RTWmodal" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style='height:1000px;'>
    <div class="modal-content modal-tall" style='height:1000px;'>
    <div class="modal-body" style='height:1000px;'>
```

And this increases the overall modal however the main body of the modal remains at a set height with scroll bars? See below:

[image]

What am i not doing right here?

**UPDATE - Full Modal code**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="RTWmodal" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style='height:1000px;'>
<div class="modal-content modal-tall" style='height:1000px;'>

<div class="modal-body" style='height:1000px;'>
<h4 id="myPanelModalLabel" class="modal-title">Right to work </h4>

<hr>   

    *CONTENT*



</div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please create a code snippet of your code

Comment: Can you post all of the relevant modal code?

Comment: Updated question with code @XenioGracias

Comment: Updated question with code @Zim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
.modal-tall .modal-body 
{
 position: relative;
 min-height: 600px;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new modal class`modal-tall`

```
.modal-tall .modal-body 
{
 position: relative;
 min-height: 600px;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

Use like this:

```
 <div class="modal tall fade" id="RTWmodal" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content modal-tall" >
```